# Gather duplicating rows

Tags: r, transpose

Newbie again in need for help.

I'm stuck with a transpose that is duplicating rows.

My data is structured like this:

```
id date client status  agent_1 agent_2 agent_3...agent_10  flag_1 Flag_2 Flag_3  order_num_1 Order_num_2
1  xxx   yyy   01        A1        C2    E3
2  xxx  yyyy   02        B1        D2    F3
3  xxx  yyy    03        C1        E2    G3
```

I want:

```
id  date   client  status  agent flag  order_num
1    xxx    yyy     01      A1
1    xxx   yyyy     01      C2
1    xxx   yyy      01      E3
2
2
3
3
```

The client information will repeat and the columns _1 to _10 will become rows.

I have the code below. The first gather agent works perfectly but then when I run the next gather it duplicates my df, with all possible combinations.

```
 df1 <- df %>% 
      select( id,
              created_on,
              date_reported,
              client_name,
              status_code, 
              starts_with('agent'), 
              starts_with('Flag'), 
              starts_with('order_num'),
              starts_with('order_date'),
              starts_with('manufacturer'))  %>%
      gather(key, value = "agent", starts_with('agent')) %>%
      select(-starts_with('key'))%>%
      filter(!is.na(agent))
      gather(key1, value = "flag", starts_with('Flag'))%>%
      gather(key2, value = "order_num", starts_with('order_num'))  %>%
      gather(key3, value = "order_date", starts_with('order_date'))   %>%
      gather(key4, value = "manufacturer", starts_with('manufacturer'))
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried `group_by` agent but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `gather` would use `pivot_longer` from latest `tidyr` package (which essentially is its replacement).

With example data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  date = sample(seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-01"), by="day"), 6),
  client = c(rep('y', 6)),
  status = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
  agent_1 = c('A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F1'),
  agent_2 = c('C2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2'),
  agent_3 = c('E3', 'F3', 'G3', 'H3', 'I3', 'J3'),
  flag_1 = c('H4', 'I4', 'J4', 'K4', 'L4', 'M4'),
  flag_2 = c('K5', 'L5', 'M5', 'N5', 'O5', 'P5'),
  flag_3 = c('Q6', 'R6', 'S6', 'T6', 'U6', 'V6')
)

  id       date client status agent_1 agent_2 agent_3 flag_1 flag_2 flag_3
1  1 2018-01-06      y      1      A1      C2      E3     H4     K5     Q6
2  1 2018-09-25      y      2      B1      D2      F3     I4     L5     R6
3  1 2018-07-20      y      3      C1      E2      G3     J4     M5     S6
4  2 2018-05-23      y      1      D1      F2      H3     K4     N5     T6
5  2 2018-08-01      y      2      E1      G2      I3     L4     O5     U6
6  2 2018-10-16      y      3      F1      H2      J3     M4     P5     V6
```

You can do the following:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(starts_with("agent"), starts_with("flag")),
               names_to = c(".value", "group"),
               names_sep = "_")
```

Which would give you:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 7
      id date       client status group agent flag 
   <dbl> <date>     <fct>   <dbl> <chr> <fct> <fct>
 1     1 2018-01-06 y           1 1     A1    H4   
 2     1 2018-01-06 y           1 2     C2    K5   
 3     1 2018-01-06 y           1 3     E3    Q6   
 4     1 2018-09-25 y           2 1     B1    I4   
 5     1 2018-09-25 y           2 2     D2    L5   
 6     1 2018-09-25 y           2 3     F3    R6   
 7     1 2018-07-20 y           3 1     C1    J4   
 8     1 2018-07-20 y           3 2     E2    M5   
 9     1 2018-07-20 y           3 3     G3    S6   
10     2 2018-05-23 y           1 1     D1    K4   
11     2 2018-05-23 y           1 2     F2    N5   
12     2 2018-05-23 y           1 3     H3    T6   
13     2 2018-08-01 y           2 1     E1    L4   
14     2 2018-08-01 y           2 2     G2    O5   
15     2 2018-08-01 y           2 3     I3    U6   
16     2 2018-10-16 y           3 1     F1    M4   
17     2 2018-10-16 y           3 2     H2    P5   
18     2 2018-10-16 y           3 3     J3    V6
```

**Edit**: Other alternatives include `reshape` (base R) and `melt` (`data.table`).

For `melt`, the `id` would contain a vector of `id` column names in this case (or can use column numbers 1:4), the `measure` variable is a vector of column names to melt - and in this case uses a `pattern` which is regex based (`^agent_` and `^flag_`), and `value.name` for the final column names you want to use for these new variables (in this case, `agent` and `flag`).

```
library(data.table)

melt(setDT(df), 
     id = c("id", "date", "client", "status"), 
     measure = patterns("^agent_", "^flag_"),
     value.name = c("agent", "flag"))[order(id, date)]
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Thank you for your help. I forgot to mention that I can't use pivot_longer because my workplace doesn't allow packages update without updating the version of R. Is there any other function that is equivalent to pivot_longer?